Tiempos de respuesta elevado al introducir valor ramdon en script de curl contra una API
Estoy utilizando un script para medir los tiempos de repuesta de una API la cual funciona y responde con tiempos dentro de lo normal, pero al incluir un valor ramdom como una X por ejemplo dentro del comando curl la salida varia con tiempos mucho mas elevados, porque ocurre esto?
comando:
curl https://a12.wms.ocs.oraclecloud.com/lapolar/wms/api/ -s -o /dev/null -w "@test.api.txt"
Script:
                     *****----------\n
Tiempo en buscar el nombre del endpoint:  %{time_namelookup}s\n
Tiempo en conectarse a la API:  %{time_connect}s\n
Tiempo que tomo al cliente conectarse a la API:  %{time_appconnect}s\n
Tiempo que toma la API en devolver datos:  %{time_pretransfer}s\n
Tiempo que tomo en iniciar la devolución de datos:  %{time_starttransfer}s\n
                     ----------\n
Tiempo total:  %{time_total}s\n***** 



Es cosa de leer el man de curl:

If you specify URL without protocol:// prefix,  curl  will  attempt
to
guess  what  protocol  you might want. It will then default to HTTP but
try other protocols based on often-used host name prefixes.  For  exam‐
ple,  for  host names starting with "ftp." curl will assume you want to
speak FTP.

¿Cuales son esos "otros protocolos"? Recurriendo nuevamente a la sabiduría de la man-page:

curl  is  a tool for transferring data from or to a server. It
supports these protocols: DICT, FILE, FTP, FTPS, GOPHER, GOPHERS,
HTTP,  HTTPS, IMAP,  IMAPS,  LDAP,  LDAPS, MQTT, POP3, POP3S, RTMP,
RTMPS, RTSP, SCP, SFTP, SMB, SMBS, SMTP, SMTPS, TELNET or TFTP.

Entonces, cuando pones "x" sin más, curl tiene que examinar todas y cada una de esas posibilidades, lo que toma tiempo.
También debes considerar la demora tratando de resolver "x" en el DNS.
Finalmente, no puedes esperar que los accesos a un host público demoren siempre lo mismo. Eso depende la carga que tenga, número de usuarios, etc.
